# Is it possible to SPLIT into specific delimiter columns?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with multiple delimiters, but not all cells have all delimiters
i.e.

```
delimiter *@#
*text1@text2#text3
*text1#text3
```

I there a way to SPLIT into

```
col1   col2   col3
text1  text2  text3
text1         text3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for the examples you have provided:

```
=if(and(left(A1)="*",countif(A1,"*#*")=1,countif(A1,"*@*")=0),split(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#","* *"),"*"),split(substitute(substitute(A1,"@","*"),"#","*"),"*"))
```

but with this approach the formula would be a lot longer (nesting many more similar IF statements) if to cover what it seems may be other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, I had nested substitutes setup but thought there would be something more elegant / built in.